# Parameter not defined when function is ran in Python

Tags: python, function, parameters

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxhrw.png)

With the code of:

```
def sortByAveScore (bList):
  for x in range(len(aNameLst)):
    avgsorted=sorted(average)
    sortlist=list(zip(aNameLst,avgsorted))
    sortname=sorted(sortlist,key=lambda x: x[1])
  return(sortname)
sortByAveScore (bList)
```

I get the error of the parameter not being defined but if I take off the parameter, it works fine. What am I doing wrong or what am I not understanding about this? I'm new to programming so I am a little confused.

```
def sortByAveScore ():
  for x in range(len(aNameLst)):
    avgsorted=sorted(average)
    sortlist=list(zip(aNameLst,avgsorted))
    sortname=sorted(sortlist,key=lambda x: x[1])
  print(sortname)
sortByAveScore ()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z29HF.png)

Comment: Why try to give `bList` to `sortByAveScore`? It's never used in the function. Did you mean to write `bList` inside the function instead of `aNameLst`, then do `sortByAveScore(aNameLst)`?

Comment: please, show [mre]. If it says `bList` is not defined - so it is not defined, you cannot argue with the interpreter. And in the first snippet you never use the `bList` param anyway. In both scnippets you work with global `aNameList` and `average`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are working with local (avgsorted, sortlist, ...) and global (aNameLst, average) variables. The `bList` is passed as a parameter to the function, so when you try to do `sortByAveScore(bList)`,  **`bList` doesn't exist outside the function**.
That's why if you do `sortByAveScore()` (without parameters) it shows no error, because no uncreated stuff is passed to the function.

You may want to create an Object of the same type as `bList` and then pass it into the function (and it seems you may change `aNameLst` into `bList`, otherwise you are not using the `bList` anywhere).